# Login to Windows with mandatory roaming profiles for other versions of windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, roaming-profile

Hello to this community!

Recently we have been starting to research and setup a deployment for Windows 10 and use roaming profiles. Mandatory profiles are used for some users.

Our old environment is Windows 7 and we may be running a hybrid environment for a period of time between Windows 7 and Windows 10. The mandatory profiles however for Windows 7 do not login on Windows 10 and vice versa. Is there a way to select a profile based on the operating system on the machine for the user?

It's a single domain environment with 2000 users so testing is key. Any advice or suggestions are welcome too!

Comment: Mandatory profiles in Windows 7 and Windows 10 are neither compatible nor interoperable. You'll need to set up different mandatory profiles for each. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mandatory-user-profile

Comment: Hello, thanks, that's fine and more or less what I assumed. What I was looking for was a switch so that users profiles would be selected based on the OS. (or hoping it might exist rather)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows selects the correct profile version automatically. You configure a new mandatory profile for Windows 10, and copy it to the folder where your mandatory profiles are located/specified in your configuration, with the version identifier appended to the folder name.  So your mandatory profile folder would contain something like:

```
C:\MandatoryProfiles\Mandatory.V2\  <-- Windows 7/2008R2  
C:\MandatoryProfiles\Mandatory.V6\  <-- Windows 10 version 1607/Server 2016
```

Assuming the configuration (user account or policy) for the source mandatory profile specifies the location:

```
C:\MandatoryProfiles\Mandatory
```

Same concept if the source mandatory profile is located on a network share.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mandatory-user-profile#how-to-apply-a-mandatory-user-profile-to-users